# Need to add functionality in winsock control

Tags: vb6, winsock

I'm creating a application which include client & proxy server application.Both application uses winsock control.I 'm connecting client to the server by using IP address.I'm having problem with server application.It only shows the internal IP address which I don't want,what I want is external IP address i.e.Wan IP address.Is it possible with winsock?If you have a sample code please provide.Also I need one functionality server which will choose client connected to the server in list box & it will disconnect that client from the server..Please provide code.Also Once Connected to Server, If user use Internet, or any other programs, IP will show as Server's IP (Like Proxy Server).
 Here is the code for the server.

```
Option Explicit
Dim iSockets As Integer
Dim sServerMsg As String
Dim sRequestID As String

Private Sub Form_Load()

    Form1.Show
    lblHostID.Caption = Socket(0).LocalHostName
    lblAddress.Caption = Socket(0).LocalIP
    Socket(0).LocalPort = 1007
    sServerMsg = "Listening to port: " & Socket(0).LocalPort
    List1.AddItem (sServerMsg)
    Socket(0).Listen
End Sub

Private Sub socket_Close(Index As Integer)
    sServerMsg = "Connection closed: " & Socket(Index).RemoteHostIP
    List1.AddItem (sServerMsg)
    Socket(Index).Close
    Unload Socket(Index)
    iSockets = iSockets - 1
    lblConnections.Caption = iSockets

End Sub

Private Sub socket_ConnectionRequest(Index As Integer, ByVal requestID As Long)
    sServerMsg = "Connection request id " & requestID & " from " & Socket(Index).RemoteHostIP
  If Index = 0 Then
    List1.AddItem (sServerMsg)
    sRequestID = requestID
    iSockets = iSockets + 1
    lblConnections.Caption = iSockets
    Load Socket(iSockets)
    Socket(iSockets).LocalPort = 1007
    Socket(iSockets).Accept requestID
  End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the following code to show which clients are connected to my server

```
Private Sub wskServer_ConnectionRequest(ByVal requestID As Long)
  With wskServer
    If .State <> sckClosed Then
      .Close
    End If
    .Accept requestID
    ShowData "Connection from " & .RemoteHostIP & vbCrLf, True, vbBlack
  End With 'wskServer
End Sub
```

In my case the showdata function shows the text in a monitoring form, but you might write the text to file or a simple msgbox

Comment: the IP shown will be the IP which is seen by your server, so if you connect via your internal network then it will show the internal IP

Comment: Thanks for giving the solution..it was quite helpful.now what I want is to when client app is connected to server app(both are using winsock control)the client request should be forwarded to main server from the server app..please suggest something how to achieve this..need I do some coding on server app..please provide sample code..its very urgent.Thanks once again

Comment: ok I'll accept this as the answer & will post the new question please comment on that